# Chaincode Invoke by admin identity not in channel configuration

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-chaincode

I am performing chaincode invoke under following scenario:

1. I have a Hyperledger Fabric network running end-to-end till querying of the chaincode.
2. I have an admin identity which was added to channel configuration at the time of channel creation.
3. The chaincode invoke operation is set to Admins policy which states: "OR('Org1MSP.admin')"
4. I create another admin identity (with OU=admin and hf.Type=admin) under Org1MSP.

So now, can I use this new admin identity to invoke the same chaincode without configuring any changes to my channel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your organization's MSP configuration uses NodeOUs, it should work, as your certificate contains `OU=admin`.

If you have NodeOUs disabled, the second client is not an admin (only user certificates under `admincerts` MSP folder are). Then, you should update your channel with `configtxlator`, etc.

https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/msp.html#identity-classification

Comment: What if we are not using Fabric CA and I am transacting using this new admin identity from Node SDK script? How does network validate OUs in this scenario?

Comment: It does not depend at all on Fabric-CA. Whether you are using `cryptogen`, Fabric-CA, openssl, a 3rd-party CA or whatever, you finally get a MSP folder structure that you use in your channel configuration (`configtx.yaml`); and that is what determines your MSP. If NodeOUs are enabled and your client certificate is signed by your CA (or with your CA root/intermediate cryptographic material) and has `OU=admin`, it would be an admin. Without NodeOUs, only certificates under `admincerts` folder when creating the channel creation transaction are considered.

Comment: I am using a 3rd party CA. When I decode my configuration block to JSON, the MSP section of the organization shows the following entry `"fabric_node_ous": null` and `"organizational_unit_identifiers": []` and still I am able to invoke the chaincode using a certificate that is not in admincerts folder but has OU=admin. Why is this happening?

Comment: Show me how have you defined your policy (or how it is shown in the JSON configuration block).

Comment: Okay I understood the issue. The peer/Propose policy is set to Writers by default and that policy for my organization is set to signing of `OrgMSP.member` which means that any identity from OrgMSP can particularly perform the invoke operation. If I change this policy to `OrgMSP.admin` then it will fail for the given new identity if NodeOUs are not configured, like you explained. Thanks for clearing it out. Found my mistake.